# When does Grails assign an ID to an object?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

A Grails `2.3.4` application is connecting to an Oracle database using the following domain class:

```
class Person {

    String name

    static mapping = {
        id column: "PERSON_ID", generator: "sequence", params: [sequence: 'person_seq']
    }
}
```

The `PersonController` makes a call to a method in `PersonService` and it makes a call to `UtilService`. The method in `UtilService` being called has some logic based on wether this `Person` object is new:

```
if (personInstance.id == null) { ... }
```

What I have found is that the `id` property of `personInstance` (which is passed through the method calls described above) is assigned when the `UtilService` is called.

The controller action calling `PersonService` is `@Transactional`, and the services do not have any transaction configuration.

So, a couple of questions:

- When is `id` value assigned by GORM (I assumed at insert but that seems wrong)?
- Is there a better way of checking if the object is new (`isAttached()` returns `true` so that's not good for me)?

EDIT: `save()` has not been called on the `personInstance` when `UtilService` does the `id` check.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what your problem is: are you expecting the ID to still be null after calling `save()` or is ID still null even after you saved it? Otherwise in your case (using a sequence generator) I'd say the ID is populated as soon as your save is flushed - if you'd like to rush that you could call `save(flush:true)`.

Comment: Otherwise, perhaps due to bad experience, but I wouldn't rely on GORM internal to see whether an object was just saved. You could use a `transient Boolean newlyInserted` property on the domain class that you would set after `save()`, wrap the instance into a POGO or command object (which would contain e.g. an `newInstance` property), or simply have an extra parameter on your service methods.

Comment: @GregorPetrin, the `id` has a value before I have called `save()`, hence my confusion.

Comment: I see, that changes things.. you could try some plain old `println` debugging to see when the instance actually gets saved: create a method `def beforeInsert() { println "Saving Person object!" }` in your domain class and other `println` statements in your code.

Comment: It was a `findBy` which was flushing the session and this flush was populating the `id` (as far as I can tell, posted an answer describing how I dealt with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had a `findBy` which was flushing the session:

```
utilService.someMethod(Person.findByUsername(username))
```

It was at this point that the `id` was populated.

Got around it by using `withNewTransaction`:

```
def personInstance = Person.withNewSession { Person.findByUsername(username) }
utilService.someMethod(personInstance)
```

Which now leads me onto the [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502758/using-findby-in-transactional-context)...

Answer (score 1):

The id is assigned when you call `save()`. For most persistence calls, Hibernate delays flushing the change until it feels it has to flush) to ensure correctness. But `save()` calls are treated differently. I believe the motivation is that even if we know that flush() will eventually be called, even if it's at the very end of the request, we want to retrieve the id  early so it doesn't suddenly change.

Note that a service that does "not have any transaction configuration" is transactional - the only way to get a non-transactional service is to remove all `@Transactional` annotations (the newer Grails annotation and the older Spring annotation) and add

```
static transactional = false
```

All other services are transactional, although you can configure individual methods to be ignored ## Headin.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I haven't called `save()` on `personInstance` when the `id` is checked in `UtilService`. Hence my confusion. It is almost like that calling the `UtilService` flushed the hibernate session...

Comment: It was a `findBy` which was flushing the session and this flush was populating the `id` (as far as I can tell, posted an answer describing how I dealt with it)