# Using findBy in transactional context

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, transactions, grails-orm

Given:

- controller `PersonController` with a `@Transactional` action `save`
- service `PersonService` with a method `populateProperties(PersonInstance)` being called from the controller action

I'd like to populate `personInstance` properties based on some data already persisted in the database, like this:

```
def personLookupData = PersonLookupData.findByUsername(personInstance.username)
personInstance.firstName = personLookupData.firstName
```

The `findByUsername` method flushes the hibernate session and in order to avoid it (because it has been giving me problems described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27309229/when-does-grails-assign-an-id-to-an-object)), I do this:

```
def personLookupData = PersonLookupData.withNewSession { PersonLookupData.findByUsername(personInstance.username) }
personInstance.firstName = personLookupData.firstName
```

This does what I want (lets me use `findBy` without flushing the session), and this is fine when there is only a couple of `findBy`s to use, but given a deeper call stack (in terms of services) and more database lookups in different places, using `withNewSession` everywhere becomes a bit ugly.

Apart from making a `PersonLookupService` which will collect all the required data in one `withNewTransaction` block and return it, is there any other nice (groovy) way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should move @Transactional from PersonControlller to PersonService.

If you have more service calls to include in the same transaction, you need to use a Transaction boundary gateway, that's marked as @Transactional and calls all services you need for the current business case.

It's not the responsibility of the MVC components to control transactions. The transactions boundary are handled by the service layer.

Comment: I agree with removing the annotations from the controllers, but it won't have an effect here. It will remove transactions and persistence from the web tier where they don't belong, and centralize that in services, which  much more sensible location.

Comment: But encapsulating all the processing login in one service method will automatically give you one transaction and one session. Opening a new session to fix something is a "code smell".

Comment: That can work for demos, tutorials, and toy apps, but it's completely unrealistic for applications that actually do stuff. You can call multiple methods in different classes and be in the same transaction and session - it's what happens most of the time, since the default propagation setting is REQUIRED. Hibernate flushing during a transaction does not commit the transaction, or create a second one, or anything of the sort. Flushing is simply clearing a cache.

Comment: I haven't found any such scenario. If you don't use JTA then it means you are employing resource local JDBC transactions. In this case the life-cycle of your transaction is bound to the life-cycle of the database connection. Usually you have a single session for that db connection. In your case you'd have to make sure all sessions see the same JDBC connection and a session close shouldn't trigger a connection release.